# Jquery no me permite comunicarme via $.ajax si entro con http y no https

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

cuando accedo a mi pagina web con http y no con https e intento ejecutar una funcion $.ajax no me permite; investigué y di con que es algo de "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"

y la solucion seria poner esta cabecera en el php a consultar con ajax; esto me parece raro ya que la consulta lo estoy haciendo desde el mismo servidor solo varia el https

mi codigo php:
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://miweb.com,https://www.miweb.com,http://miweb.com,http://www.miweb.com");

Answer (score 1):

No es un problema de jQuery, puedes intentar hacer llamadas asíncronas sin jQuery y tendrás el mismo problema.

El problema es se esta violando la **["same-origin-policy" (política de seguridad del mismo origen)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)**, esta te obliga en este caso a hacer ***llamadas https*** para que funcionen.

Del ejemplo de la documentacion, si tuvieras esta URL:

`http://store.company.com/page.html`

la siguiente no cumple la politica "same-origin-policy" (falla el protocolo):

```
https://store.company.com/page.html
```

Entonces:
hay que usar URLs con `https` para un dominio con `https`, y `http` si no tienes SSL.

Comment: y la solucion cual seria ?

Comment: @IntruzO el simple, redirige de http a https, no es saludable para tu sitio que puedas ingresar a ambos protocolos